# Ruby map a hash and extract the keys with values if nested or not

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, dictionary, methods, hashmap

I’m using the PaperTrail gem to track changes in my `Job` model. Each time I change a record, the object is serialized and stored inside a `changeset` field on my `Version` model.

To display the values that have changed, I’m deserializing the object and iterating through it using `map`. I need help creating a method that extracts all the keys and values from this hash, regardless of whether they’re nested or not. The nesting will never be more than one level deep.

Here is my current code:

```
# deserializing the object into a hash

json_string = v.changeset.to_json
serialized_json = JSON.parse(json_string)

# current method to extract keys with values, but doesn’t pick up nested ones

serialized_json.map { |k,v|
  puts k.titleize
  puts v[1].present? ? v[1] : '<empty>'
}

# serialized_json (1st output)

{
  "name" => [
    [0] nil,
    [1] "Epping Forest"
  ],
   "job_address" => [
      [0] nil,
      [1] "51 Epping Forest, Essex, ES1 SAD"
  ]
}

# serialized_json (2nd output)

{
  "quote" => [
    [0] {
      "quote" => {
        "url" => nil
      }
    },
    [1] {
      "quote" => {
        "url" => "/tmp/uploads/1433181671-22986-9554/file.pdf"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The values I’d like to extract from my method are:

```
"Name"
"Epping Forest"

"Quote Url"
"/tmp/uploads/1433181671-22986-9554/file.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your below code, I assume you're putting *[0]* and *[1]* as index numbers to help the readers of your code, as it is not valid Ruby syntax.

```
"name" => [
    [0] nil,
    [1] "Epping Forest"
  ],
```

As for extracting 1 level deep keys and values, since it's a bit unclear to me how you would like your output formatted, I'ma ssuming a 1-D array is fine...in which case, something like this would give you the keys and values:

**serialized_json hash w/valid Ruby syntax**

```
{
  "name" => [
    nil,
    "Epping Forest"
  ],
   "job_address" => [
      nil,
      "51 Epping Forest, Essex, ES1 SAD"
  ]
}
```

Then:

```
serialized_json.map { |k, v| [k, v] }.flatten.reject { |x| x.nil? }
```

outputs:

```
["name", "Epping Forest", "job_address", "51 Epping Forest, Essex, ES1 SAD"]
```

Comment: That hash is exactly as it was printed in my console. This could be a problem with the hash not being valid Ruby as I parsed it using `JSON.parse`. I have amended my question above to provide a bit more background on what I did.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps :)

```
@str = ""
def hash_checks(hash)
  hash.each do |k,v|
    if v.is_a?(Array)
      v.each_with_index do |element, index|
        if element.is_a?(Hash)
          @str = element[index] + @str if hash_check(element)
        else
          @str << k.titleize + "\n" + element + "\n" unless element.nil?
        end 
      end
    elsif v.is_a?(Hash)
       @str << k.titleize if hash_check(v)
    end
  end
  puts @str
  end

def hash_check(hash)
  add_tag = false
  hash.each do |k,v|
    if v.is_a?(Hash)
      @str = k.titleize + " " + @str if hash_check(v)
    else
      @str << k.titleize + "\n" + v + "\n" unless v.nil?
      add_tag = true
    end
  end
  add_tag
end
```

I've excluded the `'<empty>'` value for nil because the data you would want to extract is the one that matters.

There's an inconsistency on the data you want though, since on your first serialized json, there are 2 non-nil values, but you just want one.

This method includes both, and runs even for multi-level nests :)

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. I’ve just tried it and I’m currently getting `undefined method '<<' for nil:NilClass` on the line `@str << k.titleize + "\n" + element + "\n" unless element.nil?`. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: You might not have initialized `@str ` as an empty string. The only way for that error to occur is if  `@str == nil`. You can replicate the error if you want. Just run the line `@str << k.titleize + "\n" + element + "\n" unless element.nil?` and set/initialize the 2 variables as control while you set the test variable to `nil` to see what triggers the error :)

Comment: Could this be because I’m calling the method from an ActiveAdmin view, with the method stored inside `application_helper.rb`?

Comment: Theoretically, it shouldn't be since  it's an independent script. Have you copy pasted the script, or have you tweaked it? You could try running it as a ruby script first using predetermined hashes to check if the error persists :) If it still doesn't work, kindly place here your `application_helper.rb` so I can check